# Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.View.propTypes.style')

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

Making IOS build of React native for the first time:)
Can't make release build to IOS. Debug build works.
Only release and Testflight not working. 
App crashes ( closes) after it opens. 
I cleaned the cache, reinstall packages but still the same error occurs.
Versions of react and react-native:

```
   "react": "16.2.0",
   "react-native": "0.53.3"
```

My error messages from console in Xcode:

```
[error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a 
registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-03-05 22:40:26.891072+0200 agMedica[713:91027] Module AppRegistry 
is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-03-05 22:40:26.912175+0200 agMedica[713:91025] *** Terminating app 
due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: 
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'u.View.propTypes.style')', 
reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
'u.View.prop..., stack:
<unknown>@649:1548
d@2:755
<unknown>@648:81
d@2:755
<unknown>@435:171
d@2:755
<unknown>@434:81
d@2:755
<unknown>@342:201
d@2:755
<unknown>@305:141
d@2:755
<unknown>@12:42
d@2:755
n@2:326
global code@870:8
'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1d7bfb3d 0x1ca47067 0x1ce697 0x1cc1a9 0x1d7c4354 0x1d6e82b9 
0x1d6ebe87 0x1e0cb3 0x21e0c9 0x21dd3b 0x7ff467 0x80b66f 0x802a39 
0x80bb31 0x80d76b 0x80d471 0x1d04287d 0x1d04245c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
NSException
```

Comment: This is because `View.proptypes.style` is deprecated and has been modified to `ViewPropTypes.style`. Looking at the current stack trace, it is hard to determine where you are using it.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I read some articles and found what is wrong with my project. And fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was written View.propTypes has been deprecated. I have been trying to find this piece in my code. But couldn't.
Than I look at node modules and found some of it. Change View.propTypes.style to PropTypes.style and it started to work.
Maybe this solution help to someone too, maybe someone knows better solution.
[image: View.propTypes.style code that need to change]

Comment: Nikita, is this best practice to refactor code for node modules?